# Scope for an optional has_one association with itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model Indent. On which I am using STI. An indent can be of two types Sale and Purchase. In purchase class I am using an optional has_one association.

```
class Purchase < Indent
    has_one :sale , :class_name => 'Sale', :foreign_key => 'linked_indent_id'
    # Make it work.  
    scope :unsold, lambda {includes(:sale).where('id not in (select distinct linked_indent_id from indents)')}
end

class Sale < Indent
   belongs_to :purchase , :class_name => 'Purchase', :foreign_key => 'linked_indent_id'
end
```

I just need a scope on Purchase class using which i can find all the purchases which are not having a Sale associated to them.

I am using Rails 3.2 and Postgres as database.

**Update:**

The query which is getting generated is as follows.

```
 SELECT "indents".* FROM "indents" WHERE "indents"."type" IN ('Purchase') AND 
 (id not in (select distinct linked_indent_id from indents)) ORDER BY indent_date DESC
```

Following part of the query is working fine.

```
=# select distinct linked_indent_id from indents;

 linked_indent_id 
 ------------------

        15013
        15019
       (3 rows)
```

And this is also working fine.

```
SELECT "indents".* FROM "indents" WHERE "indents"."type" IN ('Purchase') AND
(id not in (15013, 15019)) ORDER BY indent_date DESC
```

What am i missing in coupling these two parts of query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first got confused by the terms `purchase` and `sale`.  But your update I believe helped me understand the problem more.

So what I understood is anything unsold is purchases minus sales.  Following should give you that list:

```
scope :unsold, lambda {includes(:sale).select { |p| !p.sale.present? } }
```

**Update:**

A brief explanation of what's happening here:

The scope does not really do all the work in the database.  It does a SQL select of all the purchases including the joined sale first.  This gives you all the records in your `purchases` table.  Then this scope falls back to Ruby `Array` on the `select` method.  The method returns all the purchases `p` without a `sale` which is done by negating purchases with sale.

Hope this clears up on what the scope is doing a bit.

**Update 2:**

A scope that's chainable!

```
scope :unsold, lambda { where('id not in (?)', Sale.pluck(:linked_indent_id)) }
```

In this scope the `id`s of Purchases that are not in `Sale`'s `linked_indent_id` are selected.

Comment: Wow. Worked in a single go.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also can you explain what have you done there a bit so that I and others can understand a bit better.

Comment: Thanks again. I thought about filtering purchases in rails but couldn't have done it in such a DRY way. Also I am going to use this scope to search while auto-completing a select menu. Bit worried if it is going to hit performance.

Comment: @Bot, please see my update.  You're right the `Array#select` is not going to make it chainable which is one of the best features of scopes in Rails.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Here is what is needed in this situation which i extracted out of your answer.
scope :unsold, where('id not in (?)', Sale.pluck(:linked_indent_id))

Comment: For the 'Purchase' rows in the table the linked_indent_id will always be null, as only 'Sale' rows have the id of 'Purchase' indent as FK. So the 'or' condition shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Bot, Glad to hear you got it working finally, and thanks for the edit.

Comment: That's the least I could have done to save you more trouble of editing. Thanks once more.

Comment: This scope again has a bug. :) 
The scope loads when the class loads. So the  "Sale.pluck(:linked_indent_id)" part doesn't get changed even after new purchases are linked. The query always contains "id not in (15013,15019)", despite changes.

Answer (score 0):

Rails-ey database-centric way to do this:

```
scope :sold, -> { joins(:sale) }
scope :unsold, -> { includes(:sale).where(sales: {linked_indent_id: nil}) }
```

(Note that you have to use the table name in the `where` clause, not the relation name.  That is 'sales', not 'sale'.)