# 'NOT IN' condition not working with 'NULL' in list

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, null

I am working on a rails 3.2 application and using postures as database.

Following query, generated by Active Record doesn't work. The code which generates this query is in this question [Scope for an optional has_one association with itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717000/scope-for-an-optional-has-one-association-with-itself).

```
SELECT "indents".* FROM "indents" WHERE "indents"."type" IN ('Purchase') AND
(id not in (NULL,15017)) ORDER BY indent_date DESC
```

But if I manually remove the NULL, and try, it works.

```
SELECT "indents".* FROM "indents" WHERE "indents"."type" IN ('Purchase') AND
(id not in (15017)) ORDER BY indent_date DESC
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is by design. You never get `TRUE` when comparing *anything* to `NULL`. I quote [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-NOTIN):

> Note that if the left-hand expression yields null, or if there are no
>   equal right-hand values and at least one right-hand row yields null,
>   the result of the `NOT IN` construct will be null, not true. This is in
>   accordance with SQL's normal rules for Boolean combinations of null values.

You can find a detailed explanation here:
[NOT IN in postgresql not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517899/not-in-in-postgresql-not-working/19528722#19528722)

If the left side of the expression (`id`) is `NOT NULL`, one way to repair this would be:

```
AND   (id IN (NULL,15017)) IS NOT TRUE
```